# How to modify data in MatLab code to be csv file

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, file-io, shortest-path

I have this following graph.
[graph I created in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY3Nz.jpg)

Currently, it works using this following data in MatLab code:

```
 function [] =  TestKShortestPath(case_number)
switch case_number
    case 1
        netCostMatrix = [inf 1 inf 1 ; 1 inf 1 1 ;inf 1 inf inf ;inf inf inf inf ];
        source=3;
        destination=4;
        k = 5; 
            otherwise
        error('The only case options available are 1');
end
```

My problem is, I want to change the data to be input file (.csv), to do so how to modify the above code (especially line 4)? Here I have my data file (in .csv which rows means edges, column 1 and 2 mean node, column 3 means cost that is the same like the above data, case 1):

```
1,2,1
2,1,1
2,4,1
1,4,1
2,3,1
3,2,1
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should get you up and running:

```matlab
% load the data from the csv file (matlab 2019a+)
data = readmatrix('your-data.csv');
% or older versions of matlab
data_table = readtable('your-data.csv');
data = data_table.Variables;
% highest number node in graph
N = max(max(data(:,1:2)));
netCostMatrix = inf * ones(N, N);
% convert the node indices to cost matrix indices and set the cost values
netCostMatrix(sub2ind(size(netCostMatrix), data(:,1), data(:,2))) = data(:,3)
```

Results in:

```matlab
netCostMatrix =

   Inf     1   Inf     1
     1   Inf     1     1
   Inf     1   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
```

Comment: I encountered this error
Undefined function 'readmatrix' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in TestKShortestPath
data = readmatrix('your-data.csv');

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realised that function was only added in matlab 2019a. I've added an alternative using the `readtable` function that should work for matlab 2013a or later.

Comment: now the error is this: Undefined function or variable 'm'.

Error in TestKShortestPath (line 24)
netCostMatrix(sub2ind(size(m), data(:,1), data(:,2))) = data(:,3)

anyway I feel thanks

Comment: if I change m to 4(=my matrix size), then I encountered this error: 
Error using sub2ind (line 52)
Out of range subscript.

Comment: Apologies, `size(m)` should have been `size(netCostMatrix)`. I've updated it.

Comment: No need apologies, you helped me a lot. It works. I really thanks so much! Hope your life getting easier cuz of helping me!